# How to get eclipse to use cocos console instead of build-android.py?

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I have Android SDK, NDK and cocos2d-x setup, and from the terminal I can build and run and android application on my device using:

```
cocos run -p android
```

The application successfully runs on my android device.

But I cannot do the same with eclipse. I open the project in eclipse by doing the following:

```
Import -> Existing Android Application -> Path to proj.android
```

But the build fails,

> 09:00:28 **** Build of configuration Release for project myprojectname
>   **** python /pathtomyproject/proj.android/build_native.py -b release all  sh: cocos: command not found Please use cocos console instead.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/pathtomyproject/proj.android/build_native.py", line 43, in 
>       build(opts.build_mode)   File "/pathtomyproject/proj.android/build_native.py", line 28, in build
>       raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!") Exception: Build dynamic library for
>   project [ /pathtomyproject/proj.android/../ ] fails!
>
> 09:00:29 Build Finished (took 84ms)

To get android to build from the terminal, I had to add lines to my bash_rc file for the cocos console path, and NDK env variable. I imagine I have to do something similar so that when eclipse tries to run build.py, it can call "cocos" itself.

What setting, or config change should I make?

EDIT: I edited build.py to use the full path to my cocos binary, to see if it would work, but then had another error where eclipse complains that the ANT_ROOT is not defined. All these variables are defined if I do "export" from the terminal. So rather than hack build.py, what settings changes can I make to that this works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by replacing the file "build_native.py", in the new "proj.android" directory from an older version of the same directory built under Cocos2d-X V3.3 or earlier.

Comment: That may work, but I don't think it should be the correct answer since we're going back to a previous version, and don't know what side effects could exist. We should find a way of getting the current version to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that does not involve editing the build_native.py file.

If you want Eclipse C++ build to use build_native.py correctly, within Eclipse, go to *Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment*

Now, click on *Add*, and add the following environment variables and their corresponding values according to your work environment:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = *path-to-android-sdk*
ANT_ROOT = *path-to-ant-bin*
COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT = *path-to-cocos2d-console-bin*
NDK_ROOT = *path-to-android-ndk*
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = *number-of-parallel-compiler-threads*
PATH = *${PATH}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}:${ANT_ROOT}:${COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT}*
cocos = *${COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT}/cocos*
```